# git rm -r --cached not removing submodule folder and contents

Tags: git, git-submodules

Solution:  remove `--cached` from `git rm -r --cached submodule/name`.  [Scripted](https://github.com/byrongibson/scripts/blob/master/git-rm-submodule.sh) for reference.

---

I'm trying to remove a git submodule based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule), but the submodule is not being removed.

I add the submodule, commit the changes, then delete it using `git rm -r --cached $path/to/submodule` (minus the trailing / ), commit the changes, but the submodule is still there.

I can use `rm -rf submodules/lift_sbt_24` to delete the folder and contents, but why isn't `git rm -r --cached` doing that?

(deleting the relevant section from .gitmodules works fine, is no problem, hence not mentioned here)

This is git 1.7.5.4 on Ubuntu 11.10, fwiw.  Complete example:

```
$> git submodule add git@github.com:lift-stack/lift_24_sbt.git submodules/lift_24_sbt
Adding submodule from repo git@github.com:lift-stack/lift_24_sbt.git as submodules/lift_24_sbt
Cloning into submodules/lift_24_sbt...
remote: Counting objects: 619, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (375/375), done.
remote: Total 619 (delta 172), reused 593 (delta 147)
Receiving objects: 100% (619/619), 1.74 MiB | 112 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (172/172), done.
$> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commits.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   .gitmodules
#   new file:   submodules/lift_24_sbt
#
$> git add -a
$> git commit 'added submodules/lift_24_sbt'
[master 9894113] update
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 160000 submodules/lift_24_sbt
$> git rm -r --cached submodules/lift_24_sbt
rm 'submodules/lift_24_sbt'
$> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commits.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    submodules/lift_24_sbt
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   submodules/lift_24_sbt/
$> git add -a
$> git commit -m 'deleted submodules/lift_24_sbt'
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$> ls -al submodules/lift_24_sbt/
total 1060
drwxr-xr-x 5 kurtosis kurtosis    4096 2012-04-18 17:26 ./
drwxrwxr-x 6 kurtosis kurtosis    4096 2012-04-18 17:26 ../
drwxrwxr-x 8 kurtosis kurtosis    4096 2012-04-18 17:32 .git/
drwxrwxr-x 2 kurtosis kurtosis    4096 2012-04-18 17:26 project/
drwxrwxr-x 3 kurtosis kurtosis    4096 2012-04-18 17:26 src/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kurtosis kurtosis     931 2012-04-18 17:26 build.sbt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kurtosis kurtosis     463 2012-04-18 17:26 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kurtosis kurtosis      91 2012-04-18 17:26 README.md
-rwxrwxr-x 1 kurtosis kurtosis     110 2012-04-18 17:26 sbt*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kurtosis kurtosis     131 2012-04-18 17:26 sbt.bat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kurtosis kurtosis 1041753 2012-04-18 17:26 sbt-launch.jar
$> git --version
git version 1.7.5.4
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're seeing is correct; `git rm --cached -r` does *not*, in fact, remove the files from the `working tree`, only from the `index`. If you want `git` to remove the files from both the `index` *and* the `working tree`, you shouldn't use `--cached`. See the [`git-rm` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rm) for further information.

---

Following is an explanation of what you did. I am assuming that you typed out the steps you took, rather than copying from a terminal; as far as I'm aware, `git add -a` is [not a known git-add flag](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-add); I am also fairly sure you also meant `git commit -m <message>`.

The cut-down steps you've taken:

```
# First, add the submodule. 
$> git submodule add git@github.com:lift-stack/lift_24_sbt.git submodules/lift_24_sbt
# Check that the submodule exists. (It does). 
$> git status
# Add everything to the staging area from the working tree. 
$> git add -a
# Commit all changes. 
$> git commit 'added submodules/lift_24_sbt'
```

At this point, you've successfully added the module, and everything is working as expected.
What you try to do next is to *remove* the module:

```
$> git rm -r --cached submodules/lift_24_sbt
```

**Note**: here, we do **not** remove the files from the `working index`, *only* from the `index`, because of the `--cached`:

> ```
> --cached
>        Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree
>        files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.
> ```

Then, check that we've removed the submodule:

```
$> git status
... <snip> 
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    submodules/lift_24_sbt
```

As you can see, the submodule has been deleted, and everything is good. Note, however, that the files still exist in the *working tree* - you can still view them with `ls`. :)

Comment: Thanks, and yes I meant `git add -A` and `git commit -m`.  Removed --cached from `git rm -r $1` and [scripted it](https://github.com/byrongibson/scripts/blob/master/git-rm-submodule.sh).  Maybe not wise to do this in a script, but it's at least useful as a step-by-step reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and simpliyfy your script, by using a new command (git1.8.3, April 22d, 2013), detailed in a new answer to "[How do I remove a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309)":

```
git submodule deinit
```

It should remove the submodule working tree as well as unregister it from `.git/config`.